# How to send error message to the frontend with Next.js Server Actions and React hook form

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form, next.js13

So I have a server action function like so:

```
export const sendResetEmail = async (values: FieldValues) => {
  const user = await prismadb.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: values?.email,
    },
  });

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("This email is not registered");
  }
```

Now, I want to access that error message in the frontend so that I can link it to the input field of react hook form using the setError function like so:

```
  const formSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = async (values) => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      await sendResetEmail(values);
    } catch (error) {
      setError("email", {
        type: "manual",
        message: error as string,
      });
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
      reset();
    }
  };
```

But it does not work. If I were to use API routes, I could simply have done this:

```
return new NextResponse(
      JSON.stringify({ message: "This email is not registered" }),
      { status: 400, headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
    );
```

But since its a server action, I cannot return NextResponse.
What can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to return promise rejection.
`return Promise.reject("your error message")`